# Autenticación oauth 2.0 con Facebook en servidor local

Tags: facebook, oauth2

¿Como hay que configurar una aplicación de Facebook para realizar autenticación oAuth 2.0 en localhost?.

Actualmente, he definido una aplicación en Facebook Developers con la siguiente configuración:

> - App Id: ...
> - App Secret: ...
> - Display Name: ...
> - App Domains: localhost
> - Site URL: http://localhost/

El resto de parámetros tienen el valor por defecto.

Para realizar las pruebas estoy utilizando Postman, al que paso los siguientes parámetros en la sección de autorización:

> - Authorization URL: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
> - Access Token URL: *Utilizo una url de mi servidor*.
> - Client ID: *El mismo que el de la aplicación facebook*
> - Client Secret: *El mismo  que el de la aplicación facebook*
> - Scope:
> - Grant type: Authorization code

Sin embargo cuando presiono 'Get access token', obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> La configuración de la aplicación no permite la URL proporcionada.:
>   Una o varias de las URL proporcionadas no están permitidas por la
>   configuración de la aplicación. Deben coincidir con la URL del sitio
>   web o con la URL de la página principal de la aplicación, o bien el
>   dominio debe ser un subdominio de uno de los dominios de la
>   aplicación.

Comment: aca esta la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850461/cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domains-in-fa/46850462#46850462) al problema

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que Facebook no puede ver la url `http://localhost/` debido a que es un alias al equipo.

Debes cambiar la url por la publica de tu servidor

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar ese tipo de pruebas te recomiendo usar **LocalTest.me** 
aquí encuentras la documentación http://readme.localtest.me/ 
Funciona de la siguiente manera: al utilizar el dominio localtest.me, todos los subdominios que puedas necesitar dentro de localtest.me apuntan a 127.0.0.1 esto quiere decir que no necesitas cambiar el archivo host de tu sistema operativo ya que simularan como si fuera tu localhost. Éxitos con el desarrollo!

PD: Tu app debe estar corriendo en algún servidor web de tu computadora bajo el puerto 80 para que accedas desde http://localhost

Comment: He modificado la configuración de la aplicación en Facebook. Sin embargo me sigue dando el mismo error, no se si me falta establecer algún parámetro de configuración.

Comment: tienes toda la url bajo el dominio de localtest.me ?

Comment: Si, bueno en realidad estoy utilizando un subdominio de localtest.me, pero creo que debería de funcionar. Igual es algún problema en los parámetros  de configuración de facebook.

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo de algo similar, espero te sea de utilidad: https://books.google.com/books?id=PHzbbSojPYIC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=localtest.me+facebook+login&source=bl&ots=5NV8-6eLMW&sig=HyQMsJWinVP8BeA0AFDJfRzDHlA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieypDhrKXLAhWEeSYKHW98ApEQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=localtest.me%20facebook%20login&f=false En caso salga algun error de la URL, el libro es "Beginning ASP.NET MVC 4 By Jose Rolando Guay Paz" Pagina 153. Y si en vez de un subdominio, vas con el dominio? En teoría hacer ese cambio temporal luego debería funcionar sin problemas. Cuáles tecnologías estas usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando hapi.js a nivel de servidor y para el cliente, a nivel de test, estoy utilizando Postman. Sin embargo, el cliente real será en Android.

Comment: Parece que voy avanzando. Ahora me aparece el siguiente error: 'No has iniciado sesión: No has iniciado sesión. Inicia sesión e inténtalo de nuevo.'. Para llegar hasta este punto, he creado una app de test (pues al parecer es lo indicado para estos casos).

Comment: estás haciendo una app híbrida?

Comment: No, el motivo de utilizar Postman es simplemente para probar un caso real del servidor sin tener que desarrollar la app.

Comment: En los parametros de configuración de facebook pide que sea https lo cual no es soportado por http://localtest.me "Los dominios de la aplicación deben coincidir con los dominios de URL segura de la página principal de la aplicación, URL del sitio para celulares, URL binaria de Unity, URL del sitio o URL segura de la pestaña de la página. Corrige los siguientes dominios: localtest.me"

Answer (score 0):

Editar "configuración del cliente de OAuth"

- Activar "Acceso del cliente de OAuth"
- Activar "Acceso de OAuth web"

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]